# Can Linux effectively remove malware from an infected NVMe drive?

Tags: malware

If yes, can you please give me the commands for this, and which distro can do better in this context?

And can I format it as an external drive or can I format while I am using it as a host system?

Comment: Do you know which malware?

Comment: Formatting by any OS or distro will remove all files (including malware) anyway. You cannot format your "host system," though you can reinstall it.

Comment: Question lacks essential info. "and which distro can do better in this context?" how does that matter?! And you are on an Ubuntu site we do not do generic Linux; the answer you get here is Ubuntu.. "Can Linux effectively remove malware from an infected NVMe drive?" What OS is on it? What malware?

Comment: I think it is ransomware. I did not how I installed exe from an ad that I downloaded. Then all my files got encrypted. I reinstalled the win 10. I worked for days and then when I turn on my PC the os can not run. Let's say I want to solve my problem on ubuntu.

Comment: "*when I turn on my PC the os can not run*." That seems like an issue better suited to a Windows support venue. Ubuntu has tools that can remove some known malware files, but is not designed to investigate, identify, and repair infected or broken Windows installations. Ubuntu seems the wrong tool for that job.

Comment: @NourdineDali if your files have been encrypted, then you cannot get them back without the encryption key. No operating system will help you.

Comment: I don't want get them back neither, I just want to format it.

Comment: I want to clarify as my question was ambiguous, I want to do something with this malware from another environment (external drive ) and I want to try to access  the integrated ssd (that in this case is not showing in the list of drives during installation of  the os.